# no show UI content for android after launching inspector in appium

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, appium

[image: no UI]

[image: Error message]

I use the eclipse mars2 and appium 1.5.3 in mac 10.12 .

I have already configured in appium (android settings,iOS setting,general setting,developer setting).

I have configured  app path,waith fo package,package,launch activity,platform nam,device name,platform version,automation name in adroid setting.

I have already changed server address(127.0.0.1) and port 4723 in general setting.

I have already checked enabled and custom server flag and enter input : --native-instuments-lib.

I use the emulator (CPU/ABI) ARM(armeabi-v7a).

I use the device Nexus5.

For my app,that emulator ARM can be run.

I have also configured in eclipse (install sdk,add ADT plugin,create emulator).

I use the android API Level 23 and android 6.0.

I can launch the inspector in appium.

But when I launch the inspector,application can run in emulator but not show UI in appium.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your appium version.
In some cases, the outdated version of appium could be the problem.

Comment: Already installed latest version.still cannot show UI in inspector